# как скачивать картинку на клик для safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код, что ниже, работает, но только не для safari

```js
$('.coupon-download').on('click', function() {

  var el = $(this);
  var url = el.data('link_coupon');
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", url);
  link.setAttribute("download", "Coupon");
  link.click();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 coupon-download" data-link_coupon="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <div class="mt-box m-b30">
        <div class="mt-media">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Почему вы делаете выборку с помощью `jquery` а свойства ставите нативным?

Comment: а что это на работу влияет?

Comment: @junior, на будущее. В целом особой ошибки нет, но лучше использовать что-то одно, нежели совмещать.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 вы можете подсказать лучше как решают подобную ситуацию что у меня в вопросе?

Comment: Для начала, перепишете всё на  `jquery`.

Comment: Отредактируй сниппет удалив часть относящуюся к php. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: @Grundy метку убрал

Comment: в разметке убери foreach, в принципе достаточно просто одного элемента `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 coupon-download" data-link_coupon="{{ Voyager::image($coupon->image) }}">` с примером конкретного url для картинки

Comment: Сервер на который ты ходишь за картинками - тоже твой? Или какой-то сторонний?

Comment: обычный хостинг доступ у меня по ftp ssh

Comment: .htacsess могу редактировать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107213/discussion-between-grundy-and-junior).

Comment: Немного переработал как описано в комментариях. Заработал и в Safari. Но возникла другая проблема. Если удалось решить, то опубликуйте код.

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, сошлитесь на эту тему как на взаимосвязанную. Обязательно опубликуйте то, что у вас получилось.