# кто нибудь знает аналог аттрибута dowload для safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

не ужели эта задача такая сложная что все для safari этот нюанс пропускает ?

как скачать файл, картинку?

Comment: а что, в safari разве файлы не скачиваются?

Comment: переходит просто по ссылке открывает в браузере

Comment: какая версия сафари? Мобильная? Десктопная?

Comment: я проверял на айфоне

Comment: Какая версия ios? Начиная с 10 версии поддержка есть: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH12-SW13

Comment: Добавь пример твое ссылки в разметке

Comment: версия 13,2 
$('.coupon-download').on('click', function() {

    var el = $(this);
    var url = el.data('link_coupon');    
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", "Coupon");
    link.click();
      

 });

Comment: вот я српашивал

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115888/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-safari?noredirect=1#comment1926547_1115888

Comment: А зачем тогда еще раз такой же вопрос задал?

Comment: так он уже далеко ушел

Comment: Прошло всего три часа - это не много, просто те, кто отслеживает метки могли его не увидеть. Если у тебя будет много плохих одинаковых вопросов, система может ограничить тебе возможность их создавать